# How to write loop in ansible with extra variable

Tags: ansible

I have got list of the mac address in the text file `mac.txt` such as:

```
[
  "08f1.ea6d.033c",
  "08f1.ea6d.033d",
  "08f1.ea6d.033e",
  "08f1.ea6d.033f",
  "b883.0381.4b.20",
  "b883.0381.4b21",
  "b883.0384.d51c",
  "b883.0384.d51d"
]
```

Now I want to check one by one above mac addresses in switch, to verify the connectivity of the server & switch and all these mac addresses may not be exist on the switch. Let's say only two exist and that mac needs to be stored in variable.

Note: these mac addresses may vary.

And here is the switch playbook which I was writing:

```
- name: Run the show lldp neighbors command & find out the switch port
  ios_command:
    commands: show mac address-table | in {{ macdress }}
  with_item:
    - macaddress
```

What is the correct playbook to achieve the requirement?

Comment: Have you already imported the mac addresses from the text file to your with_items variable "macaddress"?

Comment: not yet imported the mac address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your text file is  a valid json list, you simply have to read its content using the [`file` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/file.html) and load it inside a variable using the [`from_json` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data). You can then use the variable (in a loop or anything else).

```
---
- name: Load values from json file demo
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    macaddresses: "{{ lookup('file', 'mac.txt') | from_json }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Show imported macs list
      debug:
        var: macaddresses

    - name: Loop over imported macs
      debug:
        msg: "I'm looping over mac {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ macaddresses }}"
```

**Note**: `loop` is the recent syntax for looping and is the equivalent of `with_list`. In this situation you can perfectly replace it with `with_list` or `with_item` which are not deprecated and will do the same job. See the [ansible loop documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) for more info.

Comment: thanks it works but now need to check in the switch.

Comment: You have an example loop with debug since I don't have a compatible switch to test with. Simply replace `debug` with `ios_command` and its parameters and you're done.

Comment: Now once loop start it will find or out put of the the playbook withh return only 2 or three mac out of the 8 mac from the list, and i want to store the mac only which is find on the switch by running switch task then how can i do it.. just for FYI-- switch will return the macaddress along with port number..

Comment: [register](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) the result of running the task and loop over the result to get the info you need ? See as well the specific doc of [registering with a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop)

Comment: basically whatever output i will get from the loop from each command i want to store in variable and the one which doent have any return value or fail the task i dont want to store that value in variable.

Comment: You have all the info you need to go further and try to acheive your result now you can load your variable, loop over it and register the result or your task. I (and many others here....) don't have an IOS compatible switch to experiment. Try to do something on your own and ask a new question based on an [MCVE](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) containing your data structure and what you want to achieve if you are still stuck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help will surely share the details going forward.